# What would make SQL Agent Job fail on step that checks for other running processes?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms, ssis-2012, sql-agent-job

I have a SQL Agent Job, where the first step is to check for related processes to see if any are running, and if so, to fail the job. So here is the code for the first step:

```
    USE SSISDB; 
IF EXISTS 
(
SELECT
    TOP 1
    *
FROM catalog.executions
WHERE folder_name = 'MasterControl'
      AND project_name IN ('AJRR', 'SER', 'RC')
      AND status = 2
     )
BEGIN
    ;THROW 51000, 'Job is still running previous instance. Fail', 1
    END
```

For some reason, even though the select query itself shows no results, it does not pass the step. Did I do something wrong with the throw code?

Let me know if you need further clarification.

Here's the error message from logs:

> Check for other running jobs,,Executed as user: ROSEMONT\MasterControlQaUat. Incorrect syntax near 'MasterControl'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 102)  Incorrect syntax near 'Job'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 102).  The step failed.,00:00:00,15,102,,,,0

Comment: *"For some reason, even though the select query itself shows no results, it does not pass the step. "* If the `SELECT` returns no results, then the error won't be thrown, and therefore the step will succeed. Do you actually, therefore, want `IF NOT EXISTS`? That seems unlikely based on your description, but you seems to be expecting it to error if there are no rows.

Comment: @Larnu correct that's how it should operate. However, the select query returns no results, but the step still fails.

Comment: So, in the steo, what is the reason for the failure?

Comment: @Larnu added the log message to the original question

Comment: *"Incorrect syntax near 'MasterControl'...Incorrect syntax near 'Job'."*.... It's erroring because you have a syntax error. Reading the error helps. I suspect we don't have the whole statement here.

Comment: It's odd though, the statement itself runs just fine in a New query window.